# Java BufferedReader filepath issue

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to use a text file to populate a 2D array for a game board. I can't seem to get the reader to actually read the file though. I keep getting the following error:

> "Unable to open file 'C://git/cse116f16/src/boardpieces/board.txt'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".

I know it's because I'm not using the correct syntax for the filepath, but I can't for the life of me figure out what that should be. I have it stored at `C:\Users\myname\git\cse116f16\src\boardpieces\board.txt`.

What is the string I would need to pass into FileReader to read this file?

---

**EDIT**: Here's the method, maybe the problem isn't what I think it is.

Also it should be noted this is on a git repository so I need to be sure it can be read by everyone who pulls it.

```
    public Character[][] populateArray(String fileName){
        String line = null;
        Character[][] retVal = new Character[26][28];
        int lineNum = 0;
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            //Assigns each character to it's corresponding place in the array
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
                    retVal[lineNum][i] = line.charAt(i);
                }                   
            }   
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");                  
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public void populateBoard(){
        String path = "C:\\Users\\myname\\git\\cse116f16\\src\\boardpieces\\board.txt";

        Character[][] arr = populateArray(path);

        //the rest of the method...
```

Comment: I am not clear here, whats the need of \\ instead of \, I am able to do it by using only one slash only, as well can you share the content of your file to provide better answer

Answer (score 1):

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\myname\\git\\cse116f16\\src\\boardpieces\\board.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
String text;
while (reader.hasNextLine()){
    text += reader.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Try to display it as code by adding four spaces in front of your code.

Comment: You could do it be writing \\\\ instead of \\

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\myname\\git\\cse116f16\\src\\boardpieces\\board.txt";
//or "C:/Users/myname/git/cse116f16/src/boardpieces/board.txt"
File file = new File(fileName);
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
```

The slashs must either be like `\\` or like `/`.

*(Both `\` and `/` work but since `\` is an escape character java reads `\` this as an escape character, so by adding another one you essentially only write only slash.)*

Then you try to open the `File` and then pass it to the `FileReader`

Comment: @Bryan The problem is that you are doing `new FileReader(fileName)`, you should be doing `new FileReader(new File(fileName))`

Comment: @Bryan Did you remember to change `myname` to your username?

Comment: @Bryan I recommend going to the actual file location click on `copy path`, then using your IDE, notepad++ or any other editor, replace all the \ with /. (That's what I do).

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
final File file =
        new File("C:\\Users\\myname\\git\\cse116f16\\src\\boardpieces\\board.txt");
final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
```